# Is there a reason to toggle MSExcel.Excel.ApplicationClass.DisplayAlerts?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

In a project I've taken over, I found this code:

```
private MSExcel.Excel.ApplicationClass _xlApp;
. . .
_xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
_xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

Since I don't know why MSExcel.Excel.ApplicationClass.DisplayAlerts would be toggled from false to true with no code in between, I will leave it like it is for now anyway, but why would this toggle be beneficial or necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One case: 
If you use a macro/VBA to delete sheets from the workbook and don't want the msgbox saying "Are you want to Delete this worksheet?" to pop up, then you

```
_xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
ActiveWorkBook.WorkSheets("Sheet2").delete
_xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

and the code will delete Sheet2 without prompting the user to click ok, and more importantly for me, the routine will run to completion while you're getting coffee.

Comment: I read it as "why would this toggle be beneficial or necessary?" as in why in the world would anyone want to turn the DisplayAlerts off or on? That is why I answered like I did. Looking at the toggle as it is displayed in the OPs example, it looks like a remnant of something like I described, which has since been (partially) deleted.

Comment: Yes, what I'm looking for is either, "Sure, get rid of it, it's crazy" or "Now wait a minute, there is one obscure situation where it might help to toggle it, as strange as it appears on the surface."

Comment: DisplayAlerts = true by default. Turning it off then on with no code between is crazy. Since you inherited this craziness, search to find any other place before this code where the DisplayAlerts is turned off. Removing the two lines in question would result in that prior DisplayAlerts = false remaining false. Check ahead in the code for DisplayAlerts = false. The author may have intentionally turned it on to trigger user interaction and that will break if you remove the two lines in question.